# Incrementing values when values changes in different column in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, csv, dax

i want to change values when id values changes to different in excel
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8Rod.png)

| ID | ChangedId |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 22 | 2 |
| 22 | 2 |
| 25 | 3 |

Any help will be thankfull.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service, so unless you have already tried something that didn't work, and you want to find out why, you will probably not get an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,IF({1,0},A$1:A1,B$1:B1),2,0),MAX(B$1:B1)+1)
```

[image]